# The future expression of start, get started

Tags: difference

- `After he comes, this party is gonna start`
- `After he comes, this party is gonna get started`
- `After he comes, it's gonna get this party started`

What is the nature one?

ps. My question title's grammar is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me start by saying that "after he comes" does not sound natural at all. You would probably be better off using "when he comes", "once he comes", "as soon as he comes" and the likes.
If you need the sentence to sound more formal, you could go for "Upon his arrival".

There are many ways to express a sequence of events in the future. Here are a few examples:

Using "start":

1. This party will start as soon as he comes
   OR:
2. This party is going to start as soon as he comes

Using "get started":

3. This party will get started as soon as he comes
   OR:
4. This party is going to get started as soon as he comes

Using future perfect simple:

5. Only when he comes the party will have started
   OR:
6. Only when he comes the party will have gotten started